# phpspreadsheet composer not installing

Tags: composer-php, phpspreadsheet

I am running composer locally to generate the necessary files that I will then deploy separately to server.  Therefore I am running:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --ignore-platform-reqs
```

However, it is failing:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I am not familiar with composer.  I have tried the solution suggested here https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/971 by adding `"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet":"^1.0"` to the composer.json, but that didn't work.  I have also tried setting the minimum stability to `dev` with no luck.

Can someone help?

Edit with more info***

I have PHP 7.2 installed, full .json is the same as available from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Here:

```
{
    "name": "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet",
    "description": "PHPSpreadsheet - Read, Create and Write Spreadsheet documents in PHP - Spreadsheet engine",
    "keywords": ["PHP", "OpenXML", "Excel", "xlsx", "xls", "ods", "gnumeric", "spreadsheet"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "LGPL-2.1-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Maarten Balliauw",
            "homepage": "http://blog.maartenballiauw.be"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mark Baker",
            "homepage": "http://markbakeruk.net"
        },
        {
            "name": "Franck Lefevre",
            "homepage": "http://rootslabs.net"
        },
        {
            "name": "Erik Tilt"
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "check": [
            "php-cs-fixer fix --ansi --dry-run --diff",
            "phpcs --report-width=200 --report-summary  --report-full samples/ src/ tests/ --ignore=samples/Header.php --standard=PSR2 -n",
            "phpunit --color=always"
        ],
        "fix": [
            "php-cs-fixer fix --ansi"
        ]
    },
      "require": {
        "php": "^5.6|^7.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-libxml": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "ext-xmlreader": "*",
        "ext-xmlwriter": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-zlib": "*",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.7",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.0",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.0.0",
        "jpgraph/jpgraph": "^4.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "@stable"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "mpdf/mpdf": "Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer",
        "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "Option for rendering PDF with PDF Writer",
        "jpgraph/jpgraph": "Option for rendering charts, or including charts with PDF or HTML Writers"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\": "src/PhpSpreadsheet"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheetTests\\": "tests/PhpSpreadsheetTests"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: v1.0 requires PHP 5.6. Does your PHP version cover that? Can you share the whole `composer.json` and some version information about your environment?

Comment: @NicoHaase I've added detail to the question, but I also ran composer with  `--ignore-platform-reqs` flagged, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so this answer is for anyone else finding this as a newby to composer:

I assumed that composer would access the local files that I had already downloaded from GIT to configure everything.  So I was running the composer command from in the library source directory.

This is not how it works.  You need to run the composer command from within your project directory, it will pull the files over the internet and 'install' them in your project directory structure.

Comment: OMG that is so lame that nobody mentions this.. Thank you very much for helping me find the elusive autoload.php etc. etc. :)